# Vim script to indent selected code, insert code before and after selection

Tags: vim

How can I script an action in Vim that will take the selected lines, indent them once, jump to the beginning and insert some code, then jump to the end and insert some code?

The code that needs to be inserted at the beginning and end are static and don't need to change (at least, not at this point).

Comment: It should work for that too. In this particular case I'm looking to wrap some lines in a try/catch block for debugging (I need to redirect the error to stderr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say beginning text is `---` and ending text is `***`

```
:execute "normal gv>i---\<Esc>`>a***"
```

If you want to record it into a macro, say buffer "a", then starting with a visual selection, use:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> start recording into `a`
<kbd>></kbd>  indent
<kbd>i</kbd>  insert mode
<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>  start text
<kbd>Esc</kbd>  normal mode
<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>></kbd>  end of last visual selection
<kbd>a</kbd> insert after
<kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> end text
<kbd>Esc</kbd> normal mode
<kbd>q</kbd> end recording

Answer (score 2):

The following key sequence steps should work.

1. search for the start line e.g. <kbd>/mysearch</kbd>
2. <kbd>qa</kbd> - starts recoding the `a` macro
3. <kbd>Vxj</kbd> where `x` is the needed number of line(s)
4. <kbd>>></kbd> to indent
5. <kbd>ESC</kbd>
6. <kbd>'<</kbd> jumps to the start of the marked lines
7. insert whatever you want (e.g. <kbd>O</kbd> to start a new line right above)
8. <kbd>ESC</kbd>
9. <kbd>'></kbd> jumps to the end of the marked lines
10. insert whatever you want (e.g. <kbd>o</kbd> to start a new line right below)
11. hit <kbd>q</kbd> to end recording the macro.

Or something like this.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd contribute anyway.  This is how you can take a paragraph and wrap text around it.  Not exactly what you asked for but this one is just much neater if you write small nice small chunks of code.  From anywhere in the paragraph type:

<kbd>>ip</kbd> (indent paragraph)

<kbd>ki</kbd> (jump before the first line and open a new one)

type what you want at the beginning of the paragraph here

<kbd><Esc>}</kbd> (jump to after the last line of paragraph)

type what you want at the end of of the paragraph

<kbd><CR><Esc></kbd>

Caveats here are, as implied, this must be a "paragraph" (no empty lines) and this will not work properly if there is no new line after the paragraph.  To accomodate this, use <kbd>i</kbd> instead of <kbd>o</kbd> but then you will be an empty line before the bottom bit of code you insert.  You would need to write up something in vimscript if you wanted to account for this.

Here are all the strokes I use for setting up macro `t` to do a begin/rescue/end (for example) block:

<kbd>qt>ipkibegin<Esc>}orescue<CR>end<CR><Esc>q</kbd>

There are certainly better ways but this is keeping it at the marco level.